# $\{p_n\} \rightarrow p$ iff for every $\epsilon$, there exists $N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(p_n, p) \le \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Show that $\{p_n\} \rightarrow p$ if and only if for every $\epsilon_0$, there exists $N = N_{\epsilon_0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(p_n, p) \le \epsilon_0$ for all $n \ge N$.

Referring to Rudin's definition 3.1 of convergent sequence in a metric space:

> A sequnce $\{p_n\}$ in a metric space $X$ is said to converge if there is a point $p \in X$ with the following property: For every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies that $d(p_n, p) \lt \epsilon$. (here $d$ denotes the distance in $X$.)

How does changing from

> $d(p_n, p) \lt \epsilon$

to

> $d(p_n, p) \le \epsilon$

affect this definition? And how to go about proving the biconditional statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One direction of the statement is obvious: If $p_n\to p$ then the statement in the exercise holds, since $d(p_n,p)<\varepsilon$ implies $d(p_n,p)\leq\varepsilon$.

For the other direction the trick is to go to an even smaller distance. Suppose that for the sequence $\{p_n\}$ we know that for every $\varepsilon_0>0$, there exists $N=N_{\varepsilon_0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $d(p_n,p)\leq\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

Fix an $\varepsilon_0>0$ (for which we will show the condition in the definition of convergence). We apply what we know for $\{p_n\}$ but at the distance $\varepsilon_1 = \dfrac{\varepsilon_0}{2}$. Then $\varepsilon_1>0$ and so, by what we know, there is an $N=N_{\varepsilon_1}$ such that $d(p_n,p)\leq\varepsilon_1 = \dfrac{\varepsilon_0}{2} < {\varepsilon_0} $. And therefore $p_n\to p$.